# Smooth brush problem causes distortion in mesh

Tags: sculpting, remesh, smooth, sculpt-mode

Noobie here. Third day without a solution.

There is a problem occurring when using the smooth brush in sculpt mode which creates horizontal bumps instead of smoothing. The brush doesn't follow the shape of the mesh so it carves into it instead.

Tips?

Here's the file. https://we.tl/t-TWK7Ot5tUc

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: I think it's a normal problem. May be the normals of your faces are pointing at a weird angle, this would explain the orientation of the brush. Can you share the file?

Comment: pasteall.org/blend

Comment: All I can say is that, there's something with your mesh's topology that makes the brush behave like that. I thought it was normals but it seems that it is something else. One thing I can say for sure is that it's a topology problem because when I remeshed the object, the problem doesn't occur on the remeshed version.